# Can I use a keyPath in a predicate?

Tags: iphone, core-data

For some reason, this didn't work (although the keypath does exist):

The Entity is set on the Employee.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"department.departmentName == %@", departmentName];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSUInteger count = [moc countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError]; // execution simply stops at this line, with no error or console log
```

Execution just stops at the last line above when asking for the count. I don't get an console log. Also I don't get any kind of exception. The execution just stops. There are no objects in the persistent store yet. So maybe it crashes because of it tries to follow a keypath in a nonexisting object? Does that make sense?

The line where GDB stops is this:

```
0x002a31cb  <+0459>  test   %eax,%eax
```

Previously to that, I see a lot of NSSQLAdapter... calls in the stack trace. There's definitely something wrong.

Well, but when I set the Entity to the destination of the key path and then just do something like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"departmentName == %@", departmentName];
```

then there is no problem and count simply is 0.

Comment: You might want to post the code where you configure the fetchRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this "just stopping" behavior when you have a circular reference in your object graph. The fetch gets caught up in a loop. The compiler will usually warn you if this is the case but it doesn't stop you from running.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you also set the entity of the fetch request? with `setEntity:`

Comment: it's set to Employee...forgot to mention that. Sorry.